# How to detect image is grayscale

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing

I need to determine whether the image is grayscale (contains only black, white or shades of grey) or contains any color.

What libraries should I use for this?

Comment: why do you need this? what are you trying to do?

Comment: For example, ImageMagick. Or do it yourself. Your question don't full: what do you want to do?

Comment: @Srikar Appal i need to calculate printing costs

Comment: @Eddy_Em it must work without internet connection, or do you mean ImageMagick on the client side?

Comment: Yes, imagemagic library. As I said, you give too little information. Please, make your question more informal. BTW, in common case the problem is trivial, you only need to open an image, so you even can use only `libpng`, `libjpeg` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is `@borrrden` answer in code:

```
- (BOOL)isGrayScale{
    CGImageRef imageRef = [self CGImage];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);
    if (CGColorSpaceGetModel(colorSpace) == kCGColorSpaceModelRGB) {
        CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef);
        CFDataRef imageData = CGDataProviderCopyData(dataProvider);
        const UInt8 *rawData = CFDataGetBytePtr(imageData);

        size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
        size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

        int byteIndex = 0;
        BOOL allPixelsGrayScale = YES;
        for(int ii = 0 ; ii <width*height; ++ii)
        {
            int r = rawData[byteIndex];
            int g = rawData[byteIndex+1];
            int b = rawData[byteIndex+2];
            if (!((r == g)&&(g == b))) {
                allPixelsGrayScale = NO;
                break;
            }
            byteIndex += 4;
        }
        CFRelease(imageData);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        return allPixelsGrayScale;
    }
    else if (CGColorSpaceGetModel(colorSpace) == kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome){
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace); return YES;}
    else {CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace); return NO;}
}
```

Answer (score 13):

This information is present in any `CGImageRef` object.  You can get this object from any `UIImage`.  In particular, the thing you would be interested in is `CGImageGetColorSpace`.  Once you have that, you can call `CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents` on the color space.  There should only be three possibilities

`CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents` returns 1:  This image is grayscale, finished (one exception:  It could be alpha-only, but I doubt you'll be sending any images like that.  If you are, there is a way to determine whether an image is alpha only through its `CGAlphaInfo`)

`CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents` returns 3:  This image is RGB, and further analysis is needed to determine if it is grayscale or not (as the other answer states, loop over the pixels and if you find one where !(R == G == B) then it is not grayscale.

`CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents` returns 4:  This image is CMYK, and further analysis is needed.  All grayscales in CMYK should be C == M == Y (usually they will be 0, as anything otherwise would be a waste of ink [this format was developed specifically with printers in mind]) with K equal to any value.

`CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents` returns something else:  ...well...cry

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in the comments, there is a more convenient function for figuring out the color model.  `CGColorSpaceGetModel` will return values like `kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome` or `kCGColorSpaceModelRGB`.  This will take the ambiguity out of the above.  After that you can check the same way for RGB or CMYK.

Comment: Woudn't CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents return 4 even vor RGBA structured images? And are you sure that K has to have the same value as C M and Y for CYMK? Woud't it be sufficient when C, M and Y would be equal to each other?

Comment: @HermannKlecker iOS doesn't count alpha as a "color", it handles it separately.  You are right about CMYK though.  I don't have much experience with it so I just hastily threw it in there.  I will revise.

Answer (score 2):

The concept behind the grayscale is that for a pixel with Red, Green and Blue values, if the `Amount of Red = Amount of Green = Amount of Blue`, then you have an pixel with grayscale. If all pixels of your image is under this condition, it means you have a grayscale bitmap.

So, everything you gotta do is to loop over the RGB values of your bitmap. On iOS you can access the pixels of your image using the code below.

```
CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
const UInt8 * data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);
```

Comment: This assumes grayscale in an RGB model.  There is also a grayscale model, in which this way will fail.

Comment: yes, as I told, the concept behind the grayscale is that "for a pixel with Red, Green and Blue values", for other models it's different... supposing here he's working with a bitmap (iOS), therefore RGB model... but I did not know about the deep detail you offered about the CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Swift Version of approved answer

```
extension UIImage {
    func isGrayScale() -> Bool {
        let imageRef = self.cgImage
        let colorSpace = imageRef?.colorSpace
        if colorSpace?.model == .rgb {
            let dataProvider = imageRef?.dataProvider
            let imageData = dataProvider?.data
            let rawData = CFDataGetBytePtr(imageData!)
            let width = imageRef?.width
            let height = imageRef?.height

            var byteIndex = 0
            var allPixelsGrayScale = true
            for _ in 0...width!*height! {
                let red = rawData![byteIndex]
                let green = rawData![byteIndex + 1]
                let blue = rawData![byteIndex + 2]
                if !((red == green) && (green == blue)) {
                    allPixelsGrayScale = false
                    break
                }
                byteIndex += 4
            }
            return allPixelsGrayScale
        } else if colorSpace?.model == .monochrome {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```